# What does this symbol $\mathcal{B}_{\infty}$ stand for？

Tags: notation

What is the meaning of $\mathcal{B}_{\infty}(0,4\pi)$?

Comment: Without the context in which you saw this expression, it's virtually impossible to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, depends on context, but the general interpretation is:
$B_k(x,r) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n\  | \  \|x-y\|_k < r \}$ in this case, we use $\|x\|_\infty$ as the greater value between all components of $x$, for example, if $n=3$ and $x=(1,2,5)$ for example, $\|x\|_\infty = 5$

So $B_\infty(0,4\pi) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ \|x\|_\infty < 4\pi\} = \{(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \ |\  |x_i| < 4\pi \ \  i = 1,2,\cdots.n\}$
It is read as "Infinity Norm ball centered at $0$ with radius $4\pi$"

Comment: It is rare to see a caligraphic or script B denoting a ball.  My first guess is that the notation denotes the set of bounded linear operators on $L^{\infty}(0,4\pi)$, where $L^{\infty}(0,4\pi)$ is the space of essentially bounded functions on the interval $(0,4\pi)$.  Of course, without greater clarity from the asker, it is hard to know.